# NodeJS App runs on Computer but crashes on Heroku backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I have discovered that when I run my Node Application on my computer as a localhost machine using MongoLab back end it works perfectly but sadly after pushing the project using Git to Heroku server, the back end seems to fail executing the server. This is what I had found when entering `heroku logs`

```
2014-08-15T02:50:59.646594+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648767+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648760+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648770+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648758+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648766+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648769+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-15T02:50:59.648762+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-15T02:51:01.523808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teenword.
herokuapp.com request_id=baaae02b-22f3-48f3-94dc-9c272b78d1a5 fwd="184.73.33.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byte
s=
2014-08-15T02:50:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-15T02:53:14.064750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=teen
word.herokuapp.com request_id=eff2ca9e-c4d4-4ac7-9475-b8034ed8d43b fwd="31.13.157.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2014-08-15T02:56:37.094873+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by peter.soboyejo@aol.com
2014-08-15T02:59:00.813302+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-08-15T02:59:00.814146+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-15T02:59:00.814328+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817013+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817016+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817018+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817019+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817021+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817022+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:5:13)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817025+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817026+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817027+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.817029+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T02:59:00.813688+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-15T02:59:01.814561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-15T03:00:16.967002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teenword.
herokuapp.com request_id=b403ea1c-65fd-4198-a691-7ebd688db707 fwd="199.231.242.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 by
tes=
2014-08-15T03:02:03+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-15T03:02:31.673064+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-08-15T03:02:31.680188+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-15T03:02:31.680198+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693110+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693116+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693118+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693119+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693122+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693123+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:5:13)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693125+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693126+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693128+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693129+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-15T03:02:31.693131+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T03:02:28+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-15T03:02:31.679640+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-15T03:02:33.235216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teenword.
herokuapp.com request_id=92321ac0-1ee9-4dda-a782-580107c89ff7 fwd="184.73.33.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byte
s=
2014-08-15T03:05:39+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-15T03:05:57+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-15T03:05:58.051436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-15T03:06:01.982628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-08-15T03:06:00.100160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2014-08-15T03:06:01.974783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-15T03:07:37.569248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=teen
word.herokuapp.com request_id=4327c523-1ca7-49f5-8c64-b4a52b7f57b7 fwd="31.13.157.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2014-08-15T03:08:51.801138+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by peter.soboyejo@aol.com
2014-08-15T03:11:36.779299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/signup" host=tee
nword.herokuapp.com request_id=4dc53622-d8ea-40ad-9bbf-f1eb3954e9a6 fwd="24.14.146.249" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2014-08-15T03:22:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-15T03:23:11.884248+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-08-15T03:23:16.902395+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-15T03:23:11.884725+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-15T03:23:11.884916+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-15T03:23:11.884927+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887410+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887417+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887419+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887421+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887424+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887427+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:5:13)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887429+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887435+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-15T03:23:11.887437+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.901816+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-08-15T03:23:16.902692+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-15T03:23:16.902698+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904869+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904872+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904873+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904875+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904877+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:5:13)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904881+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904883+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904884+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904886+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-15T03:23:16.904887+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-15T03:23:08.660195+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b60ead0 by peter.soboyejo@aol.com
2014-08-15T03:23:18.679853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-15T03:23:08.660396+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by peter.soboyejo@aol.com
2014-08-15T03:23:29.486685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=teen
word.herokuapp.com request_id=bc8ed6e0-58cc-4aa6-9c07-0a764f35c40b fwd="31.13.157.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2014-08-15T03:23:28.867038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=teen
word.herokuapp.com request_id=6533a904-6f1c-4cf9-a5ae-d1f1adb0d85e fwd="31.13.157.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2014-08-15T03:23:15.635910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2014-08-15T03:23:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-15T03:26:52+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-15T03:27:06+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-15T03:27:10.320448+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-08-15T03:27:02.446174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" hos
t=teenword.herokuapp.com request_id=6331dbf1-aa2f-4fea-b7ed-3703705e309a fwd="50.89.215.155" dyno= connect= service= sta
tus=503 bytes=
2014-08-15T03:27:09.170120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2014-08-15T03:27:11.651208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-08-15T03:27:17.338857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teenword.
herokuapp.com request_id=86b8be74-cf19-4977-bc1b-114b383aaad9 fwd="31.13.157.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 byte
s=
```

Comment: looks like you are missing module, do `npm install` before run if you have your `package.json` configured. if not, you can do `npm install merge-descriptors`

Comment: The error, `Cannot find module`, suggests that [`merge-descriptors`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/merge-descriptors) wasn't installed with your app's deployment. If you haven't chosen to include `node_modules` in Git, you'll have to make sure [it's included in the `"dependencies"`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm) for Heroku to install it for use.